# How to create a sortedmap or treemap in velocity templates in liferay

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

How do I create a sorted map or tree map in velocity templates using liferay?

I am creating a velocity template in liferay portal. I use a `HashMap` to store some key/value pairs.

I am creating a `HashMap` like this

```
#set ($myHashMap = {
    'key1': 'value1;',
    'key2': 'value2;',
    'key3': 'value3;',
})
```

and I access the hashmap using

```
$myHashMap.get('key1')
```

I want to iterate over my hashmap and print all the key/value pairs.

But since the ordering is not maintained in `HashMap`, I want to use a TreeMap/SortedMap. I am new to velocity templates. Also, I know how to do it in java, but unfortunately the glitch is I have to find a work around in velocity templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can't create it directly in the template. The closest thing would be to create a `Map` and a `ArrayList` of keys and iterate the latter while taking values from the former.

Of course another solution is to pass a `TreeMap`/`SortedMap` created in java to the template and iterate it's `keySet`